# Directly setting a flash during integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have some content that is shown depending on some custom flash messages. 
Is there a way to directly set a flash value during an integration test?

```
class SomePageTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should keep custom flash" do
    flash[:foo] = 'bar'
    get user_path(@user)
    assert flash['foo'], 'bar' #no worky
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-three-hashes-of-the-apocalypse), the flash is available only after a request is made in integration tests.

However, the documentation for the [get](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-get) method shows that you can pass flash parameters in your test.

Please also note, that you have the `@request` instance variable handy, which has a [method for setting the flash hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/RequestMethods.html#method-i-flash-3D).

I think one of the above will work. If not, remember that flash is just a header. Setting the flash uses the `set_header` method with a [special key](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bf876aa0b61995f1be9b0146df7db74bd34d46af/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb#L39).